# how to specify editor for `sudo netctl edit`?

Tags: sudo, editors, netctl

```
~ $ echo $EDITOR
/usr/bin/kak
~ $ sudo echo $EDITOR
/usr/bin/kak
~ $ su
Password:

/home/myusername $ echo $EDITOR
/usr/bin/kak

/home/myusername $ cat ~/.profile
# nvim editor config
# export EDITOR='/usr/bin/nvim'

# kakoune editor config
export EDITOR='/usr/bin/kak'
export PAGER=$HOME/.bin/kakpager
export MANPAGER=$HOME/.bin/kakmanpager

/home/myusername cat ~/.zshenv
# nvim editor config
# export EDITOR='/usr/bin/nvim'

# kakoune editor config
export EDITOR='/usr/bin/kak'
export PAGER=$HOME/.bin/kakpager
export MANPAGER=$HOME/.bin/kakmanpager
...

/home/myusername $

but it still nano
```

Answer (score 2):

visudo and

```
Defaults env_keep += "EDITOR"
```

thanks to Sato Katsura for pointing me out

Comment: I hurried with the answer, but now it's correct

Comment: I think something should be said abut why this is. There are security risks associated with keeping environment variables - e.g.: the user could set their EDITOR variable to `/bin/bash`, then they would get a shell when executing anything that uses $EDITOR to spawn what it thinks is an editor.